# Abstract classes error display

Tags: abstract-class

```
CODE:
abstract class A
{
abstract void disp();
}
class B extends A
{
void disp()
{
System.out.println("from A");
}
void display()
{
System.out.println("Hello B");
}
}
class C extends A
{
void disp()
{
System.out.println("Hello C");
}
}
class Cls4
{
public static void main(String ar[])
{
A ob;
ob=new B();
ob.disp();
B ob1=new B();
ob1.display();
ob=new C();
ob.disp();
}
}
```

this gives error:

```
Cls4.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
ob.display();
  ^
  symbol:   method display()
  location: variable ob of type A
1 error
```

I have already declared display in class B and also defined it!!

Why cant java find it then?

Comment: The code is really hard to read. Next time you ask a question please use proper indentation/formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable ob has the static type A and class A does not have a display()-method.